# How can I remove the first character of a variable from For and Tokens in a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

With a batch script to set variable from For and Tokens and remove the first char:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8" %A in (
 'net user %username% /domain ^| 
 find "Global Group memberships"' 
) 
do set groupname=%D:~1%
```

The groupname is like *Groupname and I need to delete the * char.

I check the variable using `echo %groupname%` the output is `*Groupname:~1%`

How can I get the desired result?

Comment: Can you please explain what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: I strongly recommend you use Powershell for this.  For a couple reasons - 1) The net user command returns truncated group names and 2) powershell provides so much more capability with variable and string handling.  3) you are investing in a future proofed skill.

Comment: If you can load the AD module try this:
`get-aduser $env:username -Properties memberof |select -expandproperty memberof|get-adgroup|select name`